# After a seperator there is a key in loop. How to keep it?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, search

```
---------------------------
CompanyID: 000000000000
Pizza: 2   3.15    6.30
spaghetti:  1   7    7
ribye: 2  40  80
---------------------------
CompanyID: 000000000001
burger: 1   3.15    6.30
spaghetti:  1   7    7
ribye: 2  40  80
--------------------------
```

I'm doing a for loop over a list of lines. Every line is an item of a list. I need to keep the companyID while looking for a user input.

While this is printing the variable x=True. I cant take company ID to print it.

```
a='-'
for line in lines:
    if a in line:
        companyID= next(line)

    if product in line:
        x=True
```

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not an iterator
```

Comment: `companyID= next(lines)` try to use next for line`s`

Comment: whats your expected output

Comment: no there is the same problem i have tried it

Comment: also what is product defined as

Comment: while trying to find the product in line, i want to know whats the company id ..if there is a company iD and also i would try to know if there are many company id's

Comment: product is a user input something like : "burger"

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try3.py", line 33, in <module>
    afm= next(lines) ##afm is the company id
TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator

Answer (score 0):

You can use your line seperator to identify when new data starts. Once you see the line with "----" then you can start collecing info in a new dictionary. for each line take its key and value by splitting on ":" and create the entry in the dictionary.

When you see the next "----" line you know thats the end of the data for this company so then do your check to see if they have the product and if so print the company id from the dictionary.

```py
line_seperator_char = '-'
company_data = {}
product = 'burger'

with open('data.dat') as lines:
    for line in lines:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line.startswith(line_seperator_char):
            if product in company_data:
                print(f'{company_data["CompanyID"]} contains the product {product}')
            company_data = {}
        else:
            key, value = line.split(':')
            company_data[key] = value
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 000000000001 contains the product burger
```

Comment: how to make line.startswith("CompanyID") if instead companyID would like to to put strings from greek characters?

Comment: sorry i didnt understnad your question

Comment: im saying what if the argument of the function startswith( ) wasnt english characters

Comment: `word = "λόγος"; print(word.startswith("λό"))` still prints `True` since the string does indeed start with these chars

Answer (score 0):

No it doesnt run. Could you explain what does "[1] means near split()[1]?
Another try that doesnt run is

y=[]
    y=lines[1].split(' ')

```
for line in lines:
    y=line.split(' ')
    if len(y[1])==10:
        companyID=y[1]
    if product in line:
        x=True
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.Something that finally worked in my case was that:

```
y=[]
y=line[1].split(' ')
a='-'
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith("CompanyID:"):
        y=line.split(' ')
        companyID=y[1]
    if product in line:
            x=True
```